# Help interpret 遅れてもよければ、大丈夫だ in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Here's the full context:
A: 鈴木さん、今日来られるっていっていた? 
B: ちょっと遅れてもよければ、だいじょうぶだって。

What I understand roughly

*A: Did Suzuki say that he can come today? 

B: He said that if it's okay to be a bit late, he can come*

**But I was wondering if I misinterpret B.**

遅れてもよければ, 大丈夫だ

遅れても: even if it's late 
よければ: if it's okay 
大丈夫だ: It's okay/all is good

A. Was Suzuki san asking permission if it's okay to be late? (asking questions/permissions)

B. Or is it that he said he can come but will be a bit late and he hopes that it's okay? (A statement)

*Update: I just realised that there is no か in the end of the sentence so B is the only logical explanation...*

Comment: What really is the difference between "asking permission if it's okay to be late" and "[saying] he can come but will be a bit late and he hope that it's okay"?

Comment: @blavius asking permisson means that he will not come if he cannot be late. But in the later, he will definitely come and not asking for permissions but he's a bit sorry with his lateness.

Comment: @blavius ah...i'm sorry if the way i explain it was confusing. I was wondering if the だいじょうぶ was a QUESTION if it's okay (ask permissons) or just A STATEMENT. But i just realised that there is no か so i guess it's just a statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ちょっと遅れてもよければ、だいじょうぶだ

I imagine something like the following having taken place before B reported to A:

**B:** 鈴木さん、今日、仕事終わったら飲みに行けそう？
**鈴木:** う～ん、行くんだったらちょっと遅くなりそうな予感なんだけど…　それでもよければ、はい、大丈夫です。

(Addressing someone by family name sounds overly formal in English; let's pretend his name is Bob)
**B:** Hey Bob, you think you're going to be able to grab some drinks with us after work today?
**Bob:** Hmm, well if I do go, I have a feeling I'll be a bit late... but if that's alright, yeah, I'm in.

So your original understanding is basically right on target. This is just a conjugated form of the ～してもいい pattern.